# Gradle overriding the dependency version in a multi project

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I have a multi module gradle project and I have a dependency version conflict between 2 subprojects. By default, the subprojects resolve to the highest dependency version and causes compilation errors due to API incompatibility.

I added this configuration in the subproject:

```
configurations.avroCodeGen { // avroCodeGen is part of a custom plugin
  resolutionStrategy {
    eachDependency {DependencyResolveDetails details ->
      //force override avro to version 1.4.0
      if (details.requested.name == 'avro') {
        details.useVersion '1.4.0'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This compiles fine if I build this specific module but when I build from the top level root project I get compilation errors. I have added this in my root project build.gradle but it doesn't seem to help.

```
project(':subproject-name') {
  plugins.withType(CustomPlugin) {
    configurations.avroCodeGen {
        resolutionStrategy {
          eachDependency {DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            //force override avro to version 1.4.0
            if (details.requested.name == 'avro') {
              details.useVersion '1.4.0'
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This complains saying it cannot find property CustomPlugin in the sub project. What am I missing?

Comment: how did you apply the "CustomPlugin" plugin? I guess the problem is, that CustomPlugin is not in the classpath off the root build script. adding it to the classpath via buildscript { repositories{...} dependencies {classpath ...} should do the trick. Most likely you need to reference that class by the full qualified classname